# Laravel Undefined variable: locations error with search function

Tags: php, laravel

I have a Undefined variable: locations error with building a simple search function. It is my first time building a search function and I am really struggling with it so far.

I have 2 tables: Locations and Landmarks. One location can have many landmarks. A landmark can only have one location.

I am trying to search a Location and want the landmarks stored in the database with location_id to view when I search.

Here is my Location model relationship:

```
public function landmarks(){
  return $this->hasMany('App\Landmarks');
}
```

Here is the landmark relationship to the location:

```
  public function location(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Location');
  }
```

My SearchController:

```
  public function search(Request $request){
      $landmarks = $request->input('location');

      //now get all user and services in one go without looping using eager loading
      //In your foreach() loop, if you have 1000 users you will make 1000 queries

      $locations = Locations::with('landmarks', function($query) use ($landmarks) {
           $query->where('landmarks', 'LIKE', '%' . $landmarks . '%');
      })->get();

      return view('pages.browse', compact('locations'));
  }
```

Route:

```
Route::get('/browse', 'SearchController@search');
```

View:

```
<form action="" class="search-form" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="location" placeholder="Search" required>
    <button class="search-btn" type="submit"><i class="flaticon-026-search"></i></button>
 </form>

  @foreach($landmarks as $landmark)
    <p>{{$landmark->name}}</p>
  @endforeach
```

Comment: Are there any routes that returns the same view that you posted above?

Comment: @PaulSantos Yes `Route::get('/search', 'SearchController@index')->name('search');` and in my index method in controller - `return view('pages.search');`

Comment: Your search method was never called, the request always call the index method of your search controller. You can put the contents of your search function then move it inside your index function then try again.

Comment: That worked thank, but now I have a new error `mb_strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given`

Comment: Can you post the contents of your new index function?

Comment: `public function index(Request $request){
            $landmarks = $request->input('location');

            $locations = Locations::with(['landmarks', function($query) use 
         ($landmarks) {
                 $query->where('landmarks', 'LIKE', '%' . $landmarks . '%');
            }])->get();

           return view('pages.search', compact('locations'));
          }`

Comment: Oh shucks, I am trying to format the code but it won't, I am sorry

Comment: It's okay. I'll post an answer right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's clear that your `search()` method is never being called, we moved the contents of your function inside your `index()` method.

```
public function index(Request $request) { 

    $landmarks = $request->input('location'); 

    $locations = Locations::with(['landmarks', function($query) use ($landmarks) { 
        $query->where('landmarks', 'LIKE', '%' . $landmarks . '%'); 
    }])->get(); 

    return view('pages.search', compact('locations')); 

}
```

But then you received another error:

```
mb_strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given
```

Because your `with()` function is incorrect, the proper way to do this is:

```
with(['landmarks' => function ($query) use($landmarks) {
    $query->where('landmarks', 'LIKE', '%' . $landmarks . '%'); 
}])
```

Also, I think you are trying to get all **locations** that have a **landmark** matching a given keyword. So instead of `with()`, *which eager loads the relationship*, you might as well change it to `whereHas()` that *will filter the results if a relationship exists in a model*.

Your code would now look like this:

```
$locations = Locations::whereHas('landmarks', function($query) use ($landmarks) { 
    $query->where('landmarks', 'LIKE', '%' . $landmarks . '%'); 
})->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop over  eager loaded content , try below if you have single location and multiple landmark

```
  @foreach($locations->landmarks as $landmark)
    <p>{{$landmark->name}}</p>
  @endforeach
```

if you have mutiple location and mutiple landmark inside it try below

```
@foreach($locations as $location)
        @foreach($location->landmarks as $landmark)
           <p>{{$landmark->name}}</p>
        @endforeach
  @endforeach
```

Comment: I keep getting the same error: `Undefined variable: locations`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the error isn't that you're missing `$landmarks`? You are passing locations to your view, but then looping through landmarks.

Comment: Can you `dd($locations);` right after your query in your controller?

Comment: In your controller, you are passing a variable called `$locations`, in your view you are using a variable called `$landmarks`

Comment: @BizzyBob I already said that in my answer that you are commenting on.

Comment: I thought he needed to hear it again  :-)

Comment: Nothing happens when I `dd($locations)`, sorry I am a newbie

Comment: Then something has not saved or you are not ever hitting that controller. That method is short for die and dump, so the execution would have stopped.

Answer (score 0):

Change your location model relationship

```
public function landmarks(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Landmark');
}
```

Comment: No my model is called Landmarks - accidental plural

Comment: It is highly recommended to use the singular form of your entities when naming models.

Comment: I know that - I just forgot to do it. I will fix it later, for now I am just focused to get the search working. I need to hand this project in today and I am leaving the small stuff for later